How to retrieve the GitHub repository secrets and print their values?
While using the PyGithub package I am trying to fetch the repo secrets and trying to get their values but I am not able to do that, but I am able to access the value of GitHub repo variables
Using this piece of code I am able to retrieve the variables from the repo:
from github import Github
code = ""
github_token = f'ghp_{code}'
github = Github(github_token)

repo = github.get_repo('bhupender/repo_name')

secret_value = repo.get_variable("DEMO_TOKEN")

print(secret_value.value)

I was going through some documentation and it is written that we can't access the secrets out of the repository.
How can I access that or is there any other workaround?

It's not a PyGithub, but github itself limits.
Existing secrets can't be revealed in the web-interface nor with gh CLI application
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/using-secrets-in-github-actions
You can only list, set, or delete existing secret
